# Input text is wrapping instead of extending horizontally

Tags: html, css

All,
I have a text field that when it gets too full the line goes to the next line instead of extending horizontally.

On the right side of the following webpage you can type in an email address and make it long and the text wraps instead of going horizontally. Does anyone have any idea why it would be doing this? Is it something in my CSS? I inspected the element but didn't see anything that would be causing it.

Here is the URL:
http://tinyurl.com/bolsrcx

Thanks

Comment: Please read this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: its fine in my browser

Comment: also you should check this site http://css-tricks.com/dont-stop-the-audio/

Comment: This is sort of interesting cause text shouldn't normally wrap in an input `type="text"`. Something extra is being applied somewhere.

Comment: and also another tip, on your contact form page you have a transition:all ease ...; on your input fields & textarea i think you should change the all to background, because when i re-size the textarea it has a fit and feels very unresponsive

Comment: This is strange. I copied the computed styles for your input element into a fiddle (i.e. all the styles applied to the element by the browser), and is unable to replicate the issue on the same browser on JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/KUeyz/ However I am still seeing the issue on your site. I am using Chrome v25.

Comment: Ha! I did did the same as Terry: http://jsfiddle.net/29uF3/ No idea how you've managed to do this :-/ Something must be obviously wrong somewhere, but I just can't spot it!

Comment: It's blowing my mind too. I looked at all of the CSS elements and I can't see what is going on. I don't think this could be controlled by JS at all especially since it works in other browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `word-break: initial;` on the `<input>`

Its a new CSS 3 keyword, and luckily has -WebKit support :)

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you! I just wonder why I had to explicitly call it out like that instead of just allowing the natural text field behavior to do it's thing. Odd but fixed so thanks!